# SSRS Vertical bar chart , X axis label repeating after setting the category expression?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, report

SSRS Vertical bar chart , X axis label repeating after setting the category expression?

Repeating x axis label.[Repeat x axis label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsEHT.png)

[Repeat x axis label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY1m8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would sort the dataset by the live value if this does not do the trick then use case when  to populate your x axis labels within your sql query.